# Theme titlebar not showing gradient

Tags: android, android-theme

I wanted to create a theme for my app which looks like this:

[image]

For that, I entered this in the `styles.xml` file

```
<style name="TestAppThemeTopbar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_topbar</item>
    <item name="android:text">@string/topbar_title</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#6D929B</item>
</style>
<style name="TestAppTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:background">#F5FAFA</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">81dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/TestAppThemeTopbar</item>
</style>
```

`gradient_topbar` is an xml file with the following content:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <!--  Gradient Bg for listrow -->
   <gradientTopbar
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="81dip"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:startColor="#B7AFA3"
      android:endColor="#E8D0A9"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

I added the theme to the manifest file. And applied the theme to the project. Now in the `Graphical Layout` of `fragment_main.xml`, the appearance of the Theme is as follows:

[image]

1. The title bar gradient is not showing up
2. The text is not in center
3. The text has a white background

And I also need to do the following:

1. The text size need to be increased
2. Custom font for text
3. Font color of text

What am I doing wrong that causes the first three issues? How to solve them? And how to do the second three?

**EDIT**

This is how I added the theme to the manifest file:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/TestAppTheme" >
    .... //rest of xml
```

Comment: post your manifest.xml file

Comment: so you want to stlye your actionbar background??

Comment: title bar actually.. I don't consider it as an action bar. It's sole purpose is to show title.

Comment: howa about just a plain color does it work??

Comment: nope. still not working.